# Running a Kiosk App from session-setup-script

Tags: lightdm

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04.03 to create a Kiosk.

I want that the Kiosk displays a custom App made by us.

I'm using lightdm session-setup-script to do so.

I have created the following file:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-Kiosk.conf

[SeatDefaults]
session-setup-script=/home/keonn/Kiosk/start.sh
```

The problem is that Windows Manager is not working on the background, so I can't close the app using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

If I kill the app using SSH and kill command, it bring me back to the login Screen.

I have TeamViewer on the Kiosk to remote support and I need to be able to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and access the Desktop.

I was doing something similar on Ubuntu 12.04 and the Windows Manager was working fine.

Any idea?

Many thanks,

Alex.